# Adding a node in a transaction using py2neo

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

I have code that uses `py2neo` to create and insert a node into the node4j database.

However, I need to do this in a transaction.

`graph.create(node)` creates and commits the node.

I get a transaction by `tx = graph.cypher.begin()`

The documentation says Transaction accepts a statement. I don't have a statement, I have a Node instance.

Is there any way to convert a Node instance to a statement, or do I need to retool my code to create nodes using Cypher statements?

Or, does `py2neo` implement transactions some other way?

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty clear from the docs that Transactions are only available for Cypher statements in py2neo, since transactions are only mentioned under the Cypher API.

See http://py2neo.org/2.0/intro.html#cypher

Comment: Yes use the Cypher based transactions for all your needs !

Comment: All correct. Py2neo only supports transactions when running Cypher directly. There currently exist a few Cypher builder classes that could help but this is an experimental feature and not very comprehensive.